# What is the domain of validity of the Omega equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, meteorology

The [Omega eqation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_equation) is used in meteorology for estimate the value of the vertical velocity.

Considering that the horizontal velocity field and density is given by observation.

Under which condition this equation can be used for recover the vertical velocity and what is order of error between the real vertical velocity field and the one recovered by the Omega equation?

Comment: I vaguely remember that to derive the Omega equation, quasi geostrophy is assumed, so it can only be used to calculate the vertical velocity in atmospheric regions where this assumption holds ...